# How can I change x and y labels in this function

Tags: r, plot

I am using following code to get a graph:

```
library(lattice)
myfn = function(ddf, i, j, k){
    print(xyplot(ddf[,i]~ddf[,j], group=ddf[,k]), xlab=names(ddf)[i],ylab=names(ddf)[j])
}

myfn(iris, 1,2,5)
```

[image]

However, x and y labels are not coming properly. How can this be corrected? Thanks for your help.

Edit:
Also, how can I add a legend to this plot to show what colors indicate. Apologies for late addition of this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `xlab` and `ylab` inside the `xyplot` call.  You have them inside the `print` call, but outside the  `xyplot` call.  It's best to just remove the `print` call.

To add a simple legend, use `auto.key`. You can also use `auto.key = list(columns = ...)` to show the legend as wide instead of long form.

```
> library(lattice)
> myfn <- function(ddf, i, j, k) {
      xyplot(ddf[,i] ~ ddf[,j], group = ddf[,k],
             xlab = names(ddf)[i], ylab = names(ddf)[j],
             auto.key = list(columns = length(levels(ddf[,k]))))
  }
> 
> myfn(iris, 1,2,5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for picking up my mistake. Can a legend be added to this graph indicating colors? Should be a separate question but I will have to retype everything. Thanks for your help.